# Why can't I download a Dashboard as a CSV or Excel file?

Tags: einstein-analytics

I want to download analytic dashboards as a Excel, i have given "Download Wave Analytics Data" permission to the permission set still i have only image option to download.

[image]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Did you find a response?  I just came across this and I'll keep you posted too if I find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Dashboard has multiple widgets on it and they might come from different  dataset .

So getting all this data into csv file is not possible.

any way , you can download the results of each widget into a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and posted a duplicate question. Luckily, I figured it out after getting some help and playing around. Please use this link as a reference:
[Unable to download Tableau CRM dataset as CSV from Digital Experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/364177/unable-to-download-tableau-crm-dataset-as-csv-from-digital-experience/365563#365563)

In short, sharing has to be enable for the individual Widget as well. As the other answer indicated, a dashboard may have multiple datasets so downloading from the action menu of the dashboard itself is not the place. In stead, enable Widget Actions on the widget itself. If you have the correct setup, that should work!