# Unable to download Tableau CRM dataset as CSV from Digital Experience

Tags: digital-experience, tableau-crm, standard, crm-analytics

We want to give some of our Digital Experience users the ability to download CSV versions of datasets we create in Tableau CRM. There is a way to allow this using the dashboard component share functionality, but we can only seem to allow download as PNG (which is not *quite* what we want).

We have followed the following steps to make dashboards available in our Digital Experience.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_app_communities.htm&type=5

Then we followed these steps to allow Digital Experience Users to download dashboard or Lens data in CSV or Excel format.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_setup_download_enable.htm&type=5

However, I can only get an option to download a PNG image of the dashboard, as per this Stack Exchange post. However, I am also expecting the Download As CSV link. How can I make this option appear?
[Why can't I download a Dashboard as a CSV or Excel file?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204272/why-cant-i-download-a-dashboard-as-a-csv-or-excel-file)

The below is a duplicate of my question, so it seems. I was not allowed to post any comments so it was suggested I create a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a lot of digging, I found that there are settings that control this behavior. First of all, it's everything and all the permission stuff above that needs to be done.

Second of all, make sure that the embedded Dashboard Component has Sharing Enabled. This allows the sharing dialogue to open.

Third, and last, is that in Tableau CRM, in the dashboard, the Widget needs to have Actions enabled. This last step will enable a small option arrow to appear in the top right of your widget when viewing the dashboard, and this will allow downloading the underlying dataset.
[image: Enable Action Menu on Query]

Comment: Way to "bulldog" this and find a solution. +1 for "paying it forward" by coming back and adding this detailed answer to save future SFSErs some headache/time.

Comment: @xouns, you can accept your own answer, that way others can easily see that you don't need any further help